# In Shadow and Bone when Inej is practicing her act, is there an error in the TV show?

Tags: plot-explanation, shadow-and-bone

Shadow and Bone finishes 2 years before the Six of Crows series starts (I am not sure how long S&B is), so the Crows are 14-15 during the TV show, assuming that the continuity is unchanged (which is likely, considering that Leigh Bardugo was involved in the production). The show seems to forget that numerous times, most blatantly when Inej says the following while practicing her acrobatic act:

> I haven't done this since I was fourteen

She was around 14 during those events.

So my question is: Is that a plot hole, or am I missing something really blatant?

Answer (score 3):

The TV show has significantly altered the timelines from the books.  You can no longer assume the Crows timeline follows 2 years after the Sun Summoner timeline, and therefore work out that they should only be 14-15 years old.

When creating the show, they took aspects of the Crow storyline and merged it into Alina's story, including making the heist all about kidnapping her from the Little Palace.

Comment: Additionally, most of the actors are substantially older than the book characters, meaning that it seems likely the characters are older too. Nothing indicates that the S&B/SoC characters are teenagers.